# Messed up pip install

Tags: software-installation, python, pip, software-uninstall

I was just trying to install pip some months ago, I recall. However, I've had no use of it till date. 
I recall [visiting this site](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) and going on with the command `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`. I can also verify this as I have `get-pip.py` in my `~`. Then I also remember reading 
"*pip is already installed if you are using Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4 downloaded from python.org or if you are working in a Virtual Environment created by virtualenv or pyvenv. Just make sure to upgrade pip.*"

I obviously had Python installed, so I can remember running `pip install -U pip` and it installing the latest version, but I don't remember if I ever ran `sudo python get-pip.py` before reading the above(it is supposed to be run if you don't have python already installed).
I don't remember it but I think I did, because I have these files:

- easy_install
- easy_install-2.7
- pip
- pip2
- pip2.7
- wheel

in `/usr/local/bin` with the same modified date as that of `get-pip.py` in my home directory.

Now when I run `pip install -U pip`, it returns `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (10.0.1)`

I'm just trying to clean my system of unwanted stuff and want to get rid of this extra installation I did(if I did it). How do I proceed with it?
Thanks in advance!