# Messed up python install

Tags: python, pip

```
~$ python -V
Python 2.7.15rc1
~$ python3 -V
Python 3.6.5
```

I don't know what came default with Ubuntu but I'm sure I did install python from the website, and also pip. I don't remember any of it. How do I clean up?

Comment: What do `which python3` and `which python` show?

Comment: `~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
~$ which python
/usr/bin/python`

Comment: using 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: Yes, I know that. But as I said I messed with it AND pip. So maybe I may have them in more than one places/conflicting?

Comment: @swingcake if you *did* mess with it, it's not reflected on your system.  What exactly did you run?  If you did `pip upgrade` that'll break things, if you did a full Python source install it installs to `/usr/local/...` locations but your system doesn't reflect it (and it would)

Comment: @ThomasWard Can you take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039519/messed-up-pip-install) and tell